# Home page htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Thanks for taking the time for reading this.

I have a PHP project with a custom structure, in which the home page is inside multiple folders:

```
\web\views\site\test.php
```

I want to be able to load this page when users go directly to the index of my website but I need to keep index's URL. So, if you type

`http://example.com/` it should display the contents of `http://example.com/web/views/site/test.php` but the original URL can't change (`http://example.com/`).

Also, if users type `http://example.com/web/views/site/test.php` it should go to `http://example.com/`, so in this case URL has to change.

I have tried with other posts I've seen so far but in almost every attempt I get a `500 Internal Server Error`. Is it possible to accomplish this using only htaccess?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Kvnamo - Yes, please share your attempts so far. Also, do you need to map other URIs to files inside the `site` directory? So `example.com/hello` would map to `site/hello.php`.

Comment: I have tried using the following on a .htaccess file located at the root of my folders. Keep in mind that this also helps me to remove .php extensions at the end of URLs.

`RewriteEngine On`  

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`  

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`  

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]`  

`RewriteRule ^test /web/views/site/test.php`.

Sorry for the single line :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you , here you don't need to go for either creating or changing any thing @ .htaccess file .

All you have to do is to write the one of the follwoing codes @ index.php in main directory , **you may face error according to your server configuration,but try them one by one and you will get it :**

```
 <?php

  $test = file_get_contents("web/views/site/test.php");
  echo ($test); // option 1


 include("web/views/site/test.php");// option 2
 require('web/views/site/test.php'); // option 3
 require_once('web/views/site/test.php'); // option 4

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/web/views/site/test.php');// option 5
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/web/views/site/test.php');// option 6
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/web/views/site/test.php');//option 7     
?>
```

**Note :** make sure you put / before the path only with options 5,6 and 7

> UPDATE
>   regarding your comment below , I think what you need is the following code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yoursite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/views/site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/views/site/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yoursite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /web/views/site/index.php [L]
```

The above code will let you open every thing at main directory from web/views/site and from the path as well , so when you request 
yoursite.come/test.php is the same like when you request yoursite.come/web/views/site/test.php , so diffrent URLs with same contents

Comment: So if I have several pages using the /web/views/site/ folder structure should I do this on every single .php file?  I want to hide that.

Comment: if you want to redirect every thing at folder site or even site's sub folder . this is another issue , but your quistion is to show test.php content in index page , so if you want to open every thing directly from main domain and site folder let me know , there is solution

Comment: Well, I should have been more specific as my goal is the second scenario. I want to remove every folder trace on my URL and just display the name of every single page.

Comment: ok,so you need all requested page @ web/views/site/ only to be just from main directory, and redirect when people request the long url , am i right? i will modify if you want

Comment: if you meant to apply the above code for all different sub directories , it is not applicable , for example , there is web/views/site/page.php and another root web2/views2/site2/page.php you can not assign the same page with same name to main directory , you understand me ?

Comment: Regarding your first question, yes, but I also need that people are able to use short URLs as `http://example.com/test´. As for your second comment, I do understand, but this is not my case as every page has a different name.

Comment: ok , if you do the given code i am sure this will let you open `example.com/test and example.com/web/views/site/test.php together , if you need to cancel the seconed i will do it to let every one explore just example.com/test.php or example.com/page.php to be like coming from main directory while they come from example.com/web/views/site/ , is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, that will do the job! Thanks!